# Prevent jQuery from escaping html entities

Tags: jquery, escaping, html-entities

I have some simple html editor. Let's say that user types following:

```
<p>Ok, this just &amp; sucks :) &ndash;</p>
```

and it is saved to some variable:

```
var content = "<p>Ok, this just &amp; sucks :) &ndash;</p>";
```

Now, somewhere I'm using jQuery to append this text to some element:

```
$(this).html(content); // where content is the string above
```

The problem is that it is escaped:

```
<p>Ok, this just &amp;amp; sucks :) &amp;ndash;</p>
```

How can I achieve to have the exact string with &amp ; and &ndash ; and also to have < and not &lt ; because I need html tags?

Edit: more details added

Answer (score 11):

The problem is not that jQuery is escaping the entities.  I think if you use console.log to write the `content` string, you'll see that your editor is returning escaped entities to you.

The whole point of `.html()` vs `.text()` is that `.html()` is for HTML that will be treated as HTML.

Comment: Thanks for response. Well yes, the "content" is escaped already (it contains the same text as the first code above), but jQuery re-escape it again and so the  '&amp ; ndash ; ' is created.

Answer (score 1):

I Guess you want to have the 
text `<p>Ok, this just &amp;amp; sucks :) &amp;ndash;</p>` to be exactly shown with out converting them, so that the  `&amp;`  and `ndash;` will not be  converted to `&` and `-`, then use :

```
$(this).text(content);
```

One problem with this is that the `content` will be added as a text in site the `this` element. It will **not** create a `p` element and append it to `this`.

But if you want to take the effect of conversion then you code should work.

**One more  thing I want to mention,** I believe that language is not the only one related to those conversion. **Browser** take the main role in those cases. SO, What ever we do in the script  if browser get another chance to check the contents it will convert them to `&` and `-`.