# How to add ajax loaded content that contains an AngularJS expression with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, ajax

I got stuck with these problem and hope you can point me in the right direction.

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/44kt81yd/).

**Explainer**

1) I receive some template html via ajax request, everything works fine this is what it looks:

```
        <div>
            <h2 class="splash" ng-bind="view.headline || 'That&#039;s cool'"></h2>
        </div>
```

As you already know if the **view.headline** this will output **That's cool**

2) Adding the template to the dom (just pseudo code)

```
<div id="thisIsMyTemplatePlaceholder"></div>
<script>
var templateFromAjax="<h2 ng-bind=\"view.headline||'That&#039;s cool'\"></h2>";
$("#thisIsMyTemplatePlaceholder").html(templateFromAjax);
</script>
```

3) Inspect the added HTML you see three **'(apostrophe)** on the ng-bind attribute and this causes the my error

```
<div id="thisIsMyTemplatePlaceholder">
<h2 ng-bind="view.headline||'That's cool'"></h2>
</div>
```

4) The Problem seems to be the jQuery.html() function because it decodes the specialcharacters.

```
jquery is transforming this: 'That&#039;s cool' into 'That's'
```

Comment: You should not be mixing jQuery in with Angular, if you have a template you want to paste into a page, you should use a directive. So to solve your problem, use ng-include to paste your template.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your call for the template looks like? What is the URL structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try escaping twice.
One escape will be removed as `html()` unescapes your String, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7773553/prevent-jquery-from-escaping-html-entities) for reference.

```
'That\\'s cool'\">That's cool</h2>";
```

Now when you use `.attr("ng-bind")` the following will be the result

```
view.headline || 'That\'s cool
```

Is this your desired effect, or will only `That&#039;s cool` work?

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

First, separate the template to another file, just easier that way:

**myTemplate.html**

```
<h2 ng-bind="view.headline || 'That\'s cool'"></h2> 
<!-- you can just escape the one apostraphe, but really, 
this logic doesn't belong in the html, but rather the 
controller or service which assigns a value to view.headline -->
```

Then you can include your template:

```
<div id="thisIsMyTemplatePlaceholder" ng-include="'myTemplate.html'"> </div>
```

A Plunker showing this working:

http://plnkr.co/edit/NlzTmlNMQCqHwqVxgCpQ?p=preview

Comment: That's working, but I'm still looking for a way to do this with jquery. Thanks for the plankr!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
<!-- you can just escape the one apostrophe -->
<h2 ng-bind="view.headline || 'That\'s cool'"></h2>
```